# Powershare USB cooks external SSD

Tags: usb, ssd, cooling

I have a laptop with four Powershare (high amperage) USB ports. Whenever I plug my mSATA USB SSD enclosure into my laptop for a hour or so it gets very hot (even if it's not used at all). I don't want to damage it.

Is there any way to:

- Have the USB port suspend when not in use?

  - I have USB selective suspend enabled, doesn't seem to do anything.
- Limit the power the USB port emits?

Comment: Well, what operating system are you using?

Comment: An SSD will get warm, as it still uses power. Do you have something to measure the actual temperature as "very hot" by touch is very subjective.

Comment: Even not used, after use a SSD can have a lot of internal activity that has to still be performed, certannly dropping the power at that time would be a bad thing.  Leveling, block writes, even might be moving data out of lesser cells to preseve it.  If I had the above issue I would want to check the voltage output on this USB port, I have measured some USB power pack items at neer 5.5V, which works out sorta ok when there are voltage drops on the wiring to the devices, even if it was a bit out of "specs". There would be no requirement to do that to get "high amperage" but it is one trick.

Comment: Ah, but the thing is, even at 5 volts, the USB port runs north of 1.5 amps. Do you know how to check the voltage?

Comment: Voltmeter , USB pin diagram http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:USB.svg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be so many reasons.

- SSD is broken but still functional
- same for enclosure
- SSD does not support idle, it can't sleep when it's not used
- same for enclosure
- same for your OS
- the USB ports are broken, incorrect voltage
- some background software keeps reading/writing to the SSD, it will never sleep

If you would have provided more information (laptop model number, SSD model number, enclosure model number and what OS and version you are using), it would have been easier to exclude some possible causes and figure out how it can be done.
Have you checked where the heat is actually coming from (ssd/mSATA-USB connector without casing/both)?
If you can connect the SSD in another computer (without enclosure), try stress-testing it with repeatedly reading from the ssd, if it doesn't get hot, there is probably something wrong with your enclosure or laptop.

Comment: Both are brand new (two days old) and fuly functional. I did specify the computer model number (Dell XPS 15 9530). The computer is also new (one week old). The OS is Windows 8.1 Update. The SSD activity light is off, so nothing is accessing the disk. The problem does not reproduce on a regular USB port. (I have none on this computer, but two on my old computer).

Comment: But it's also not the Laptop as far as I can tell. External HDDs, SATA2 SSDs, and ODDs all work fine. It's just this computer with this enclosure/SSD that's the problem.